# converting string to datetime issue

Tags: c#

I have been looking around the web to find an example that will solve my issue with string convertion to datetime.

I would like to convert en-us (mm/dd/yyyy) to dutch belgium (dd/mm/yyyy) datetime. 
Could you please give me a working example?

For your information, I have tried Convert.ToDateTime, Parse, TryParse, ParseExact etc, but none was working. I really like an example that will make this conversion, no futile links.

---

Upate

The error I get is: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
What I have tried:

```
----------------
string str = "02/20/2012";
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(str);
---------------------
IFormatProvider theCultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("nl-BE", true);
DateTime theDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(deliveryDate, "dd/mm/yyyy", theCultureInfo);
Console.WriteLine(dt);
----------------------
var parsed = DateTime.ParseExact("02/20/2012","dd/mm/yyyy", null);
---------------

dateValue = DateTime.Parse(dateString, new CultureInfo("nl-BE", false));
```

and some other examples which I don't remember them now. But all leading no where.

Comment: You want string to string conversion?

Comment: DateTime should support a CultureInfo.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313781/localization-of-date-time-using-custom-patterns

Comment: I assure you that ParseExact is workng fine.

Comment: It works better with `"MM/dd/yyyy"` as format.

Comment: @Henk Could you please give me a working example, not just suggestions because I have seen a lot and I could not get it work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use these method overloads:

- [`DateTime.Parse(string, IFormatProvider)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs.aspx)
- [`DateTime.ToString(IFormatProvider)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht77y576.aspx)

and pass a [`CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.datetimeformat.aspx) to them:

```
string enUsDateString = "12/31/2012";
IFormatProvider enUsDateFormat = new CultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat;

DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(enUsDateString, enUsDateFormat);

IFormatProvider nlBeDateFormat = new CultureInfo("nl-BE").DateTimeFormat;
string nlBeDateString = date.ToString(nlBeDateFormat);
```

This will, however, also include the time component in the output. If you don't want that, try e.g.:

```
IFormatProvider nlBeDateFormat = new CultureInfo(…).DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
//                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Your last line of code gives me this error: Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider'

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:

```
DateTime date = 
DateTime.ParseExact("20122018", "dd/MM/yyyy", 
                   CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```